# What’s the best way to create a dynamic header and footer that can be used in both Vue and React applications?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, npm

I have many small projects that are children apps to a main site, each served in it’s own container in a subdomain below the father project.

This doesn’t really matter much to my question, but just for added context: the main site is an ancient Drupal 7 monster, which exposes via json the links and structure of the site’s header & footer. These links and structure don’t suffer many changes, but enough that it was necessary to provide a easy way for the children apps to update their own versions of it.

Most “children apps” are pretty simple single page apps written in Vue & React.

Currently, they’re only 3 projects, but that number will be growing this year, so I wondered if there was a way I could create a single project in charge of building a header and footer retrieving the data from Drupal, and then reutilizing that project in every Vue or React application.

Is this viable? Which framework would be better for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web component is the simplest possible way to achieve what you need. Write your Header and Footer as a web component. That way it becomes easy to incorporate into your Vue/React application. Either you can use plain Web Components or a better abstraction like Stencil or Lit-Element.

You will need polyfill to support all the browsers. Whenever your child app needs to update header or footer, for example, it can grab the instance of web component like this:

```
const header = document.querySelector("#app-header");
```

Of course, this is not a fully declarative way of doing things. If you need a declarative approach, then you can actually create a Layout component in both Vue and React and use your web components in the Layout JSX/template.

As an optional extension on a similar line, your Layout component could be another web-component which renders header and footer component along with your mini child apps. So you can avoid creating multiple framework specific layout components. However, for your case, I don't see the need.

Comment: Rude of me never to reply, thanks for your answer! We ended up going for the declarative approach, felt it was easier to maintain in the long run.